# C# Move File to folder

Tags: c#

I'm getting the error "Extensions" is a folder, not a file, when trying to run this

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.Filter = "MSL Files (.MSL)|*.MSL";
        var onlyFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog.FileName);
        bool flag = openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK;
        if (flag)
        {
            this.txtPath.Text = openFileDialog.FileName;
            File.Copy(txtPath.Text, Application.StartupPath + @"\Extensions\" + @onlyFileName);
        }
        extensionTree.Refresh();
```

How to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set onlyFileName before you show the dialog, which means it is null (empty) so it doesn't get added on to your path.